# in R, how to get an last integer in a table with both NA, string and integer

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to get the second to last integer in a table I get from read.table. I've been trying to do a loop that would search from the lower right corner to lower right corner until it found an integer, then I'll retrieve the integer right before it. Is full of an unknown number of NA values close to [nrow,ncol] until it hits integer or strings. I have been trying to use this code but it does work

```
y=0
 while (grep("^[[:digit:]]*$", b[nrow(b),ncol(b)-y])!=1) {y=y+1}
c$end<-b[nrow(b),ncol(b)-y]
```

somehow y stays 0, even though b[nrow(b),ncos(b)] is a string and not an integer.
When I try to reverse that and do

```
grep("^[[:digit:]]*$", b[nrow(b),ncol(b)-y])!=1
```

it says "=" is unexpected, so maybe there's something wrong in the while statement.
If you know what the problem is or know a better way to code this let me know.

EDIT:
So here's the read.table if it makes it a lil clearer
so the last line looks something like this. I'm interested in the second to last number in the last line of the table, which is 226882

```
17               1 round-14 224382 140 yellow 226882 190   red 226882 190 crash
```

But it's been difficult since the data is not even and sometimes the last line in this

```
13               1 round-10 161612 150 yellow 164112 200   red     NA  NA
```

in this case I'd want 164112. So I have been trying to write a code that would read from the right to left, ignoring the NA at the end and read the second integer they encounter.

Comment: OP why not at least provide `str(b)` results, or even better, a reproducible example.

Comment: I think you are looking for not an integer per se but a string that contains only numeric (`[0-9]+`) regardless of the data type, correct?  And you are searching left to right, then top to bottom?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 for the table I'm looking for integer. basically I'm looking for the last integer entry to the right, among a bunch of NA and strings. I edited my post to show you my read.table

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, try this:

```
set.seed(7)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA, 1, 2, 3, 4), 12, replace=T), 4))
  X1 X2 X3
1  4  1 NA
2  1  3  2
3 NA  1 NA
4 NA  4  1

unname(tail(na.omit(unlist(df)), 2)[1])
[1] 2
```

If you need it done rowwise, do this first, `df <- data.frame(t(df))`,

```
unname(tail(na.omit(unlist(df)), 2)[1])
[1] 4
```

In response to your edit I'll add character strings. The same function call above will work,

```
df$X4 <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA)
df$X5 <- c(NA, NA, NA, 'blue')
df[4,1] <- 'red'
df
    X1 X2 X3 X4   X5
1    4  1 NA NA <NA>
2    1  3  2 NA <NA>
3 <NA>  1 NA NA <NA>
4  red  4  1 NA blue
```

According to your example, you would like `4` returned,

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.numeric)
df <- data.frame(t(df))
unname(tail(na.omit(unlist(df)), 2)[1])
[1] 4
```

Comment: elegant approach, the transpose - unlist logic

Comment: Just noticed that. unraveling data frames makes them easier to work with sometimes.